# Array of Int and String: Update only Int value?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make a chore app for (my) kids. I´m using a tableView with custom cells. For now, I have a fixed list (array) with different chores, and a doneButton for when the chore is done. I also have a label that counts the times that chore is done.
I also have a second View Controller that is used to sum up all the chores that is done, and the amount of times they are done.
So, when the doneButton on the chore "do dishes" is pressed, the second View Controller should show: 1 Do dishes.
If the done button on "do dishes" is pressed again, the second View Controller should show: 2 Do dishes.
And when the doneButton on the chore "walk dog" the second View controller should show:
2 Do dishes.
1 Walk dog.
My problem is that I cannot get the list in the second View Controller right. When the doneButton is pressed, its either overwriting the list, or adding like this: 1 Do dishes. 2 Do dishes 1 Walk dog.
Im trying to use a array, and append to this, but I can't figure out how to update only the Int, and not the String.
This is where I'm at:

When doneButton is pressed:

```
summaryArray.append(String(choreList[indexPath.row].count) + " " + choreList[indexPath.row].chore)
```

How can I update the `count` in the array without doing anything else to the array?

Comment: Separate the number of chores from the kind of the chore. Create a struct `struct Chore { let name : String; let counter : Int }` and use this.

Comment: You could use a struct and then update only the Int. EDIT: Jinx!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a struct like so:

```
struct Chores {
    let choreName : String
    let choreCounter : Int
}
```

Then you can fill an array with all the items you need like so:

```
var array = [Chores(choreName : "Walk Dog", choreCounter : 0),//etc. you can add more]
```

With this method you can change each individual item in the array:

```
array[0].choreName = "Walk Dog faster!"
array[0].choreCounter += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have much experience with struct´s I'm afraid. How can I implement this when I'm using a tableview? How can I fill the array? Is it not possible to use `choreList[indexPath.row].chore` and  `choreList[indexPath.row].count` from the original array?

Comment: It is, actually. If you want to know more about tableView cells and how to implement them, check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAWO9rldyUE)  tutorial on YouTube. That tutorial is one of the simplest tutorials I know of, and the guy explains everything.